# Contenteditable jumping to the another element when use arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html

If contenteditable have span element at the end of the text and when using arrow keys its jump to another contenteditable.

For example; I'm moving arrow keys on the second contenteditable when my cursor came at the and cursor jump to the third contenteditable section. But cursor must stay in second section.

```
<div class="container translationSectiontargetText" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr"  >
before
</div>

<div class="container translationSectiontargetText" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr"  ><span class="tag" data-number="1" contenteditable="false">1</span>target content<span class="tag" data-number="1" contenteditable="false">1</span></div>

<div class="container translationSectiontargetText" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr"  >
after
</div>
```

And this is jsfiddle link;

https://jsfiddle.net/7jf80nv8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will help you

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
divs.forEach(div => {
 div.onkeydown= event => {
   let position = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
    let first_span_text_length = div.querySelectorAll('span')[0].innerText.length;
   let text_length = div.innerText.length - first_span_text_length - 1 
   if(event.keyCode == 39 && position == text_length){
    return false;
   }
}
});
```

```html
<div class="container translationSectiontargetText" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr"  >
before
</div>

<div class="container translationSectiontargetText" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr"  ><span class="tag" data-number="1" contenteditable="false">1</span>target content<span class="tag" data-number="1" contenteditable="false">1</span></div>

<div class="container translationSectiontargetText" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr"  >
after
</div>
```